# SQL Server not applying permissions after creating a schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following;

```
USE [$(db_name)]
GO

IF SCHEMA_ID('$(schema_name)') IS NULL
    -- Must use dynamic SQL because 'CREATE SCHEMA' must be the first
    -- statement in a query batch.
    EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA [$(schema_name)]')

-- User already exists at this point.
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[$(schema_name)] TO [$(user_name)]
```

When executed through `sqlcmd.exe`, no errors are reported and the schema is created, but the permission are not granted. If I then execute the last line in SSMS (substituting the `sqlcmd` variable), it works as expected.

Is there a reason why SQL Server won't do what I ask?

**Edit:** should have said, it's SQL Server 2008 (10.50.1617).

**Edit 2:** Oh lord, turn out the deploy framework was dropping and recreating the user. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried running the `GRANT` statement as dynamic sql? Just an idea...

Comment: I tried running it in the same EXECUTE but the server didn't like it. I haven't tried running it as a separate EXECUTE - I'll give that a go.

Comment: Immediate suspect is scoping, anything inside Execute runs in it's own scope, I'd put the grant in there as well. Must confess no idea whether it will or won't work or why.

Comment: It does get very peculiar about what you're allowed to pass in  parameters; dynamic sql usually gets around it if you have to.

Comment: Just guessing.. Try add GO after IF+EXECUTE block (before GRANT). EXECUTE and GRANT will be send to SQL Server in separate steps.

Comment: Already tried that, didn't help. I also tried putting the grant in a different file and invoking sqlcmd a second time, and *that* didn't help. I'm flummoxed :-(

Comment: @RoryHunter Please could you post your answer as an answer (and accept it) rather than an edit to your original question? It would make any potential searchers who find this question more likely to see it (as otherwise it'll come up in searches as having 0 answers).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the database user in question was being dropped and then recreated later on in the deploy process. That explains why there were no errors from `sqlcmd.exe`, and why the existence check I added before the `GRANT` didn't complain, and why running the `GRANT` manually afterwards worked as expected.